# R: Average pairs of columns in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, average

I have a large matrix made up of many columns. I would like to get a new matrix with the same number of rows and half the number of columns by averaging every nearby 2 columns (for example column 1 with 2, column 3 with 4, etc). 
Now I'm using a for loop, but I was wondering whether there was a smarter way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a vectorized solution:

```
m <- matrix(1:96,8);
m;
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
## [1,]    1    9   17   25   33   41   49   57   65    73    81    89
## [2,]    2   10   18   26   34   42   50   58   66    74    82    90
## [3,]    3   11   19   27   35   43   51   59   67    75    83    91
## [4,]    4   12   20   28   36   44   52   60   68    76    84    92
## [5,]    5   13   21   29   37   45   53   61   69    77    85    93
## [6,]    6   14   22   30   38   46   54   62   70    78    86    94
## [7,]    7   15   23   31   39   47   55   63   71    79    87    95
## [8,]    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72    80    88    96
(m[,seq(1,ncol(m),2)]+m[,seq(2,ncol(m),2)])/2;
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
## [1,]    5   21   37   53   69   85
## [2,]    6   22   38   54   70   86
## [3,]    7   23   39   55   71   87
## [4,]    8   24   40   56   72   88
## [5,]    9   25   41   57   73   89
## [6,]   10   26   42   58   74   90
## [7,]   11   27   43   59   75   91
## [8,]   12   28   44   60   76   92
```

Comment: How about just `(m[,c(TRUE, FALSE)] + m[,c(FALSE, TRUE)])/2`

Comment: @David Arenburg thanks but I get an error saying: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. do you know what the problem is ? I did it like tis (df[c(TRUE,FALSE)]+df[c(FALSE,TRUE)]/2)

Comment: @Nemo It should be `(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)] + df[c(FALSE, TRUE)])/2`